# ViewPager2 is scrolling to first position when child is modified

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, android-viewpager2

This is my Viewpager2 setup

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/homecard"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/Rooms_Layout">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Everytime a textview within a child is updated, it jumps to the first position. I found out it has something to do with notifydatasetchanged, but im not even calling it.

Im updating my data via databinding.

this is my adapter

```
private inner class ViewPagerAdapter(activity: MainActivity, mFragments : MutableList<Fragment>, mFragmentIds : MutableList<Long>) : FragmentStateAdapter(activity){
    private var fragments : MutableList<Fragment> = mFragments
    private var fragmentIds : MutableList<Long> = mFragmentIds

    fun addFragment(fragment : Fragment, fragmentId : Long){
        if (fragmentIds.contains(fragmentId)) return
        fragments.add(fragment)
        fragmentIds.add(fragmentId)
        notifyItemInserted(fragments.lastIndex)
    }

    fun removeFragment(fragmentId: Long){
        if (!fragmentIds.contains(fragmentId)) return

        val index = fragmentIds.indexOf(fragmentId)
        fragments.removeAt(index)
        notifyItemRemoved(index)
        fragmentIds.removeAt(index)


    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return fragmentIds[position]
    }

    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
        return fragmentIds.contains(itemId)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = fragments.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling ``notifyItemRemoved`` before removing the fragment ID, so that could cause some problems when an ID is fetched by index. But why would a change to a *TextView* in a fragment have any effect on the ViewPager it happens to be displayed in? Youll probably have to show the code that "updates" that TextView and how it interacts with the adapter

Comment: The removing and adding of fragments is no problem. My problem occurs, when a child gets its textviews updated. There is no difference if they get updated from the viewmodel, from inside the fragment itself or manually by the text attribute. Every time they get fresh text, my viewpager scrolls to position 0 :/

Comment: The ViewPager and its adapter have no concept of anything changing in a TextView in a Fragment, so your code must be doing something that (directly or through a series of side-effects) causes the ViewPager to refresh its state. Also check your logs to see if there are any warnings, in case something is causing errors that cause your views to be recreated. This isn't normal behaviour

Comment: Same here, did you find any solution??